# update_field() funktion does not affect Advanced Custom Fields radio buttons in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I was working on a class method that would go through image posts on my Wordpress site 10 images at a time, check if there is a human in the image with the help of the Clarifai API and then change two Radio-Buttons from Advanced Custom Fields to show if the image has been checked and if the image contains a human. The checking of the images does work however if i want to change the custom fields with the "update_field()" function it doesn't change the radio-Buttons of the checked images.

```
class FaceDetection {
    public function getErgebnisImageArray() {
        $ergebnisImageArray = array(); 
        $field_id = 0;
        $triumveret = 0;
        
        $rd_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'virtual_run',
            'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft'),
        ));

        if($rd_query->have_posts()){
            while ($rd_query->have_posts()) { // loop the posts
                $rd_query->the_post();
                if(have_rows('ergebnis')) {
                    while(have_rows('ergebnis')) {  // loop the ergebnis 
                        the_row();
                        if( have_rows('beweis') ){
                            while(have_rows('beweis')) { // While there are rows that have the beweis field
                                the_row();
                                if(get_sub_field('checked') == 'no'){  // if the sub field has not been checked before ...
                                if(count($ergebnisImageArray) < 10){   // if the array has less than 10 entries
                                    echo "getsrunonce ";
                                    $image_url = get_sub_field('url');   // get the value from the sub field url
                                    $fullpath = get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $image_url;  // make the full path
                                    $field = get_field_object('checked');   // get value from the checked field
                                    $human_field = get_sub_field_object('mensch');  // get the value from the human field
                                    $field['ID'] = $field_id;
                                    $human_field['ID'] = $field_id + 1;  // always up the value from the human field by one
                                    $idOfField = $field['ID'];
                                    $idOfHumanField = $human_field['ID'];
                                    $ergebnisImageArray[$triumveret] = array('image_url'=> $fullpath, 'field_id'=> $idOfField, 'field_id_human'=> $idOfHumanField);  // insert array with url and the two field id's

                                    $triumveret++; // increase the value so that the next entry can be added
                                    $field_id+=2;  // so that the ids go up each run
                                }
                                
                                    if(count($ergebnisImageArray) == 10){ // If there are 10 entrys in the $ergebnisImageArray send them to clarifai
                                       $detection = new clarifaiAccess; // new class instance
                                       $api = $detection->clarifai($ergebnisImageArray); // give array to class method
                                       $data = $api;   // returnes an array with the resultt

                                    foreach($data as $arrayitem){  // foreach array in the returned array 
                                        $resultDetection = $arrayitem['value']; // get the value if it was a human or not (true/false)
                                        $fid = $arrayitem['fieldId'];     // get the id of the first field
                                        $hfid = $arrayitem['humanfieldId'];   // get the ai of the second fields   
                                

                                        if($resultDetection == true){       // If clarifai returns Binary-Positive the array gets the value of true
                                          update_field("checked", "yes", $fid); // Update the checked field in the backend
                                          update_field("mensch", "yes", $hfid); // Update the human field in the backend
                                          echo " True(" . $fid . " " . $hfid . ") ";
                    
                                        }elseif ($resultDetection == false){   // If clarifai returns Binary-Negative the array gets the value of false
                                          update_field("checked", "yes", $fid);  // Update the checked field in the backend
                                          update_field("mensch", "no", $hfid );  // Update the human field in the backend
                                          echo " False(" . $fid . " " . $hfid . ")";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $ergebnisImageArray = array(); // clear the array
                                    $triumveret = 0;     // reset the array input placement
                                }
                                } else{
                                    echo "It was already checked; ";
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

As can be seen added some echo's to see if the code ran correctly and used "var_dump()" to check the return from the clarifai method (The comments behind the lines are from me as well). As already mentioned all of it works as it should, however the fields don't get updated at all or it changes the Radio button of an image that was not sent to the Clarifai API. The update_field function did work for me before, then getErgebnisImageArray() was still checking each image individually with the API, but now after i changed the code so it could send more than one at a time to the API that is no longer the case.

This is the clarifai class:

```
class clarifaiAccess {

function clarifai($ergebnisImageArray){
  $c = 0;
  $justimages = array();

  foreach (array_column($ergebnisImageArray, 'image_url') as 
  $value) {  // take all images and put them in an array
    $justimages[] = $value;
  }

$index = 0;

foreach ($justimages as $image) {

  $newinputs[] = array(    // THIS IS HOW TO SEND MULTIPLE 
  IMAGES!!!!!!!!
    "data" => array(
        "image" => array(
            "url" => $image,
            "allow_duplicate_url" => true
        )
    ),
    "id" => "image" . ($index++)
);
}

$headers = array(
  'Authorization: ' . KEY,
  'Content-Type: application/json',
);

$data = array(
  'user_app_id' => array(
      'user_id' => USERID,
      'app_id' => APPID,
  ),
  'inputs' => $newinputs,
); 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, URLURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$responseArray = json_decode($response, true); 

$resultarray = array();
foreach ($responseArray['outputs'] as $output) {
  $regions = $output['data']['regions'];
  $human_detected = false;
  foreach ($regions as $region) {
    $concepts = $region['data']['concepts'];
    foreach ($concepts as $concept) {
      if ($concept['name'] == 'BINARY_POSITIVE') {
        $human_detected = true;
      } elseif($concept['name'] == 'BINARY_NEGATIVE'){
        $human_detected = false;
      }
    }
  }             // array('value' => $human_detected, 'fieldId' => 
$ergebnisImageArray[$c]['field_id'], 'humanfieldId' => 
$ergebnisImageArray[$c]['field_id_human']);
$resultarray[] = array('value' => $human_detected, 'fieldId' => 
$ergebnisImageArray[$c]['field_id'], 'humanfieldId' => 
$ergebnisImageArray[$c]['field_id_human']);
  var_dump($resultarray);
  $c++;
}

curl_close($ch);

return $resultarray;
} 
}
```

Comment: `$fid = $arrayitem['fieldId'];`, `$hfid = $arrayitem['humanfieldId'];` - what are those supposed to be? `update_field` takes the _post_ id as third parameter.

Comment: @CBroe The $fid takes the value of the "checked" field from the array that was returned from the clarifai() method. The $hfid does the same for the "mensch" field.

Comment: I have no idea what those are supposed to be. Are these posts, or ...?

Comment: @CBroe Both are subfields of the "beweis" Field, which is a subfield of the "ergebnis" field. As seen above if a post has the "ergebnis" field as well as the "beweis" field and the "checked" field is set to no, it will set the ID of the "checked" and the "mensch" fields. these ID's then get put into an array and sent to the api, after the image has been checked it send these ID's back with the result. I originally wanted to use these as the parameters for the update_field function however as you pointed out it can only use the post ID